# Retrieving data from temporary tables

Tags: sql

I have created a temporary table which takes in information from two joined tables, I am then trying to insert into a fourth table by selecting the attributes from one table whose `IDs` match the one in the temp table.

At the moment I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO TableX
    SELECT attributeID, attribute1, attribute2 
    FROM Table1 WHERE attributeID = attributeID IN 
#TempTable
```

But I'm being told 'Incorrect syntax near 'IN''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
INSERT INTO TableX 
SELECT attributeID, attribute1, attribute2 
FROM Table1 
WHERE attributeID IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT attributeID FROM #TempTable)
```

The `IN` keyword requires either a list of values or a subquery after it.

Answer (score 0):

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause, but not the way you specified.

`INSERT INTO TableX
SELECT attributeID, attribute1, attribute2 FROM Table1 WHERE attributeID IN (select attributeID from #TempTable)`

`IN looks for the match in selected attributeID list from #TempTable`

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
INSERT INTO TableX 
SELECT attributeID, attribute1, attribute2 
FROM Table1 
WHERE attributeID IN #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableX SELECT attributeID, attribute1, attribute2 
FROM Table1 WHERE attributeID IN #TempTable
```